Remove blank sections from map result with filter
I am using a map to 'filter' my data, but I'm getting the empty array pieces in the result. How does one alter the code to achieve this?


const WHITE_LIST = ['123', '321'];

const mapped = items.map((item) => ({
  ...item, accounts: item.accounts.map((acc) => ({
    ...acc, products: acc.products.filter((prod) => WHITE_LIST.includes(prod.code))
  }))
}));

console.log(mapped)
<script>
const items =  [
   {
    "accounts": [
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "code": "123",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "code": "321",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "code": "765",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "products": [
          {
            "code": "345",
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
   }
  ];
</script>



Current result:
[
  { products: [ [Object] ] },
  { products: [ [Object] ] },
  { products: [] },
  { products: [] }
]

Expected result:
[
  { products: [ [Object] ] },
  { products: [ [Object] ] }
]


You've shown Current result: ... which is exactly what you coded ... what is your expected result

You're filtering at the lower level, the products array, correctly. Are you then saying you want to filter the items array? Because in that case the problem is that you just... didn't do that.

maybe expected result is without the empty arrays?

@JaromandaX cmgchess is correct. I have updated the q now with expected result

@physicsboy - we shouldn't have to guess :p

if you probably want to reduce the number of loops maybe combine filter+maps into a reduce

@jonrsharpe cheers for pointing out where I should add the filter. I think I'd gotten lost in the code and the flow of it. I've gotten it to work now :-)

@cmgchess can you please give an example? I'm not the most confident with reduce unfortunately.

after looking at it again i dont think reduce is that great here.  what you have is just fine

are you sure that's your current result/expected output? I'd expect your current result to be an array of objects with  accounts property and then the array of products inside of that, not just the array of product objects you've shared? So it makes me question if that is your complete expected output, or are you expecting that to be wrapped in an object with an accounts array that's in its own array? Your solution below seems like you want accounts included?

I made a snippet. Please [edit] it to show what your attempt is supposed to look like

Just add a filter to end
const WHITE_LIST = ["123", "321"];

const mapped = items
  .map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    accounts: item.accounts
      .map((acc) => ({
        ...acc,
        products: acc.products.filter((prod) => WHITE_LIST.includes(prod.code)),
      }))
      .filter((x) => x.products.length > 0),
  }))
  .filter((i) => i.accounts.length > 0);


@physicsboy - probably due to the hard to read code, and the very brief description (wasn't me - I'd write it as a single line :p )

Bit harsh doesnt exactly need an essay!

@Ben - I'm on your side

After some hints and tips, I have gotten it to work by adding an extra filter within the existing loops, to filter after the accounts map
const mapped = items.map((item) => ({
  ...item, accounts: item.accounts.map((acc) => ({
    ...acc, products: acc.products.filter((prod) => WHITE_LIST.includes(prod.code))
  })).filter(i => !!i.products.length)
}))


This will return also {accounts: []} being empty. Is that expected?

@RokoC.Buljan are you sure? I have tested and it works correctly... My output: [{"accounts":[{"products":[{"code":"123"}]},{"products":[{"code":"321"}]}]}]

Read again my comment. If accounts is an empty array [] it gets returned anyways. And you're not testing with an empty accounts array obviously.

Ah, apologies. I don't think it'll ever reach that edge case with the data I'm using, but if I were to protect against it... what would you suggest?

I would suggest in that case @Ben's answer, since it does exactly the same as yours plus that tiny bit - if I'm seeing correctly: .filter((i) => i.accounts.length > 0);

Ah, I always wonder what the difference would be doing !!!i.accounts.length vs >0. I guess I know now :D

No accounts.length > 0 is the same as !!accounts.length which is also the same as just accounts.length (dont even need !!) but you need to account for products.length AND accounts.length whichever syntax you are using..
